# How can i reconnect Hub after lost internet in React native?

Tags: react-native, signalr

When my app lost and reconnected to internet, i can't reconnect to SignalR Hub again. Unless i turn off the app and open again.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Image, Alert, TextInput, FlatList, Button, RefreshControl } from 'react-native';

import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';

const hubUrl = '/chatHub';
let hub = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(hubUrl)
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();
hub.start();
```

Can someone teach me how to reconnect SignalR Hub after lost? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i use `hub connectionState` to check and call `hub.start()` it works well

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NetInfo` in React-native

`import { NetInfo } from "react-native"` Deprecated. Use `react-native-community/react-native-netinfo` instead.

You can run `npm install --save @react-native-community/netinfo` and `react-native link @react-native-community/netinfo`

```js
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectionChange);

}

componentWillUnmount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectionChange);
}

handleConnectionChange = (isConnected) => {
        this.setState({ status: isConnected });
        if (isConnected !== "none" || isConnected !== "unknown") {  
             hub.start();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your reply :)
I already use Netinfo in different way but it doestn't work. But i will try your way and reply you as soon as possible!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but something wrong. I put your code in my chatscreen and it works the first time, the second times it makes Error: handshake response.
I were trying to fix it but it won't helps. Can you explain how it doesn't work the second time? Thanks

Comment: @NguyễnMinhQuânNgô   This is another problem. Create and post new questions, and explain them in detail.

Comment: @NguyễnMinhQuânNgô Why did you uncheck my answer?

Comment: I'm sorry but it makes a RECALL `hub.start()` when i re-open my screen and crash. Basically its not working to reconnect. I have been using different way to reconnect it. So please understand me it really doesn't work